# Show DataGrid based on the TreeView selection in winform

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a tree view in my win form which is having more than 10 nodes, node values are read from DB and it changes dynamically, based on selection for each node I have to show the appropriate details (data will be read from DB for the grid) in the DataGrid on right side of the form, is there any simplest way to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property `TreeNode.Tag`. It is already built to contains data from `TreeNode`.
When loading `TreeNode` from database, you can load the list data for each node and put it in the `Tag` property of `TreeNode` following by code below.

```
TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(textNodeFromDb);
// for exam the LoadListDataByNodeText will return IList<Details>
treeNode.Tag = LoadListDataByNodeText(textNodeFromDb);
```

And when user select one node on the TreeView:

```
if (treeView.SelectedNode != null)
   dataGrid.ItemSource = treeView.SelectedNode.Tag as IList<Details>
```

To get more information about `TreeNode` please follow the link below. It already contains the sample code as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = getSelectedNodeDataList(myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text)
```

`getSelectedNodeDataList` should return a `List` of data for that node. If you have duplicate names on `TreeView` use `Index` instead of `Text`.